# Natural logarithms of numbers to a base

Tags: logarithms

Is the following expression valid?

$\ln_c (x)$

Natural logarithm of $x$ to the base $c$.

I have never seen anything like it, a colleague just showed it to me today and we've spent most of the day arguing about whether it's valid or not, please help out.

Comment: As far as I know, the expression "natural logarithm" assumes "base" $e$, which is Euler's Constant. You can change to any other basis, though. Could you provide context for this discussion?

Comment: I was asked to differentiate the expression

Answer (score 14):

You can write in general $\log_c(x)$ which is the logarithm to base $c$. You can further write  $\ln(x)$ which is the logarithm to base $e$ which is also called the natural logarithm (hence the abbreviation $\ln(x)$). The modes ${\rm lnc}(x)$ or ${\rm ln}_c(x)$ should not be used.

Comment: Thank you, I hope I can convince him with this.

Answer (score 3):

In general: $$\log_c(a)=b \to c^b=a$$
$\ln$ is used specifically when $c=e\approx2.71828$

Thus:
$$\ln(a)=b\to e^b=a$$
Hence, your notation is incorrect.

Comment: There is no such thing as "incorrect notation". Notation may be nonstandard, bad, or unclear, but there's nothing to be correct or not about notation.

Comment: @tomasz one might call it gibberish.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes there are little differences about the logarithm. For example, $\log$, $\ln$, $\lg$ are all used.

For example, the notation what I've learned in the high school, was this:

- $\ln$ means the $e$-based logarithm,
- $\lg$ the 10-based logarithm
- and $\log_x$ the x-based log.
- There was also $\text{lb}$, as "logaritmus binaris", the 2-based logarithm.

On this notation, $\ln_c$ is incorrect, but as there is not a really standardized one, we can suspect the meaning wanted to be $\log_c$.

Note, the important part of the Math is not the actually used notation, but what it means (or tries to mean).